# Xaxis-Tick labels have disappeared plotting with pandas onto subplot, but are still stored

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Using a complicated script that nests among other `pandas.DataFrame.plot()` and `GridSpec` in a subplot setting, I have the following problem:

When I create a 2-cols 1-row gridspec, the tick lables are all correct. When I create a 1-col 2-rows gridspec however, as soon as I plot onto the first (upper row) axes using `pandas.DataFrame.plot()`, the x-ticklabels for the top row disappear (the ticks remain).

It is not the case that the top ticks change once I draw something on the lower ax, `sharex` appears to not be the issue.

However, my x-labels are still stored:

```
axes[0].get_xaxis().get_ticklabels()
Out[59]: 
<a list of 9 Text major ticklabel objects>
```

It's just that they're not displayed. I suspected a NullFormatter, but that's not the case either:

```
axes[0].get_xaxis().get_major_formatter()
Out[57]: 
<matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter at 0x7f7414330710>
```

I get both ticks and labels on the top of the first axes when I do

```
axes[0].get_xaxis().tick_top()
```

However, when I then go back to `tick_bottom()`, I only have ticks on bottom, not the labels.

**What can cause my stored labels to not to be displayed despite a "normal" formatter?**

Here's a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import gridspec

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2), columns=['A', 'B'])

figure = plt.figure()

GridSpec = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=1)
[plt.subplot(gsSpec) for gsSpec in GridSpec]
axes = figure.axes
df.plot(secondary_y=['B'], ax=axes[0], sharex=False)
```

Comment: Would you mind creating a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make it easier to see and debug your problem please?

Comment: Yeah really need a mcve, I cannot reproduce this behavior (I've tried [this](https://gist.github.com/jmarrec/17df8922d268d63f32259f4bbe36ccfa) and it worked like a charm)

Comment: @JulienMarrec added that

Comment: Just to narrow the problem down, if I remove `secondary_y=['B']` it works as expected...

Answer (score 5):

It's the `secondary_y=['B']` that causes the xticks to disappear. I'm not sure why it does that.

Fortunately, you can use `plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)` ([docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.setp)) to turn them back on manually:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import gridspec

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2), columns=['A', 'B'])

figure = plt.figure()

GridSpec = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=1)
axes = [plt.subplot(gsSpec) for gsSpec in GridSpec]
ax = axes[0]
df.plot(secondary_y=['B'], ax=ax, sharex=True)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
```

[image: Turning xticklabels back on]

Comment: this does not work with pandas 0.25.1 and matplotlib 3.1.1, any ideas?

Comment: This bug should have been [fixed long ago](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9158). I encountered [something similar](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10162) that apparently was fixed together with 9158. Did you find any solutions?